# Setting value of radio button in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, radio-button

In my form for editing details, I have a radio button with values `0` and `1`. What I want is, while the form is loaded ie, when user clicks on `edit` link, the radio button should be set to the value in the database. Once the user have changed it and submit the form, it should retain the submitted value. How this is possible ?

I tried with the below code and it doesn't worked. I know that it can't be done this way. `$row->videotype` have the value from database.

```
<input type="radio" name="trailer" value="1" <?php 
    if(set_radio('trailer', '1', TRUE)) {
        echo set_radio('trailer', '1', TRUE); 
    } else { 
        if($row->videotype==1) ?> checked=checked <?php 
    } ?> />Yes
<input type="radio" name="trailer" value="0" <?php 
    if(set_radio('trailer', '0')) {
        echo set_radio('trailer', '0');  
    } else {
        if($row->videotype==0) ?> checked=checked <?php 
    } ?> />No
```

In form submission function (in controller) , I have set this for form validation :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('trailer', 'Trailer', 'is_numeric');
```

Can anyone help me to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `set_value` function will useful in edit form validation, try this way

```
<input type="radio" name="trailer" value="1" <?php 
    echo set_value('trailer', $row->videotype) == 1 ? "checked" : ""; 
?> />Yes

<input type="radio" name="trailer" value="0" <?php 
    echo set_value('trailer', $row->videotype) == 0 ? "checked" : ""; 
?> />No
```

In the controller the validation rules fine, please also use trim rule in case post data have blank space

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('trailer', 'Trailer', 'trim|is_numeric');
```

EDIT: the `set_radio` function create issue in edit mode form validation please use `set_value` function

Comment: If $row->videotype = 1, how does the `set_radio` know to output in the first but not the second?

Comment: this is not setting the radio button to the clicked one, once I submit the form.

Comment: @Jenz, please check update answer, hope it would work this will also checked radio in form validation.

Comment: your solution is not working with set_radio(). Any suggestion ?

Comment: @ankitsuthar `set_value()` is only using for set value of input text type, but `set_radio` function using for pre set value along with 'checked/unchecked' you can use this way `set_radio('field name', 'value', $checked = true/false)`

Comment: Yes, it's working. thank You @Girish Sir.  Can we do same for checkbox and a select box?

Answer (score 1):

The `set_radio` is a poorly documented CI function. You're not using it right. You're better off not using it. This is simpler:

```
<input type="radio" name="trailer" value="1" <?php if($row->videotype==1) ?> checked=checked <?php } ?> />Yes
<input type="radio" name="trailer" value="0" <?php if($row->videotype==0) ?> checked=checked <?php } ?> />No
```

Comment: but the problem is that, once the form is submitted it won't set to the radio button I have checked.

Comment: It would if you updated the database before you retrieve the data.

Comment: Well, the `set_radio` function doesn't need much elaborate documentation. It accepts three parameters and they are already stated in the documentation. Check my answer, I used codeigniter functions to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Using codeignitor form function:

```
<?php $selected = 'Yes'; ?>
<?php echo form_label('Trailer: ', 'trailer'); ?>
<?php echo form_label('Yes', 'trailer_yes') . form_radio(array('name' => 'trailer', 'value' => 'Yes', 'checked' => ('Yes' == $selected), 'id' => 'trailer_yes')); ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<?php echo form_label('No', 'trailer_no') . form_radio(array('name' => 'trailer', 'value' => 'No', 'checked' => ('No' == $selected), 'id' => 'trailer_no')); ?>
<?php echo form_error('trailer'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below for default value check

```
<?php
    echo $gender = $this->input->post('gender');
    if($gender=='male' || empty($gender)) $mchecked=true;
    else if($gender=='female') $fchecked=true;
?>  
<?php echo form_label('Gender: ', 'gender'); ?><br />
    <?php echo form_radio('gender', 'male', @$mchecked, 'id=male').form_label('Male', 'male'); ?>
    <?php echo  form_radio('gender', 'female', @$fchecked, 'id=female').form_label('Female','female'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the form_validation library and do this in a much elegant way.

You can use the `form_radio()` with `set_radio()` as follows:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
echo form_radio('trailer', '1', set_radio('trailer', '1', $row->videotype === "1" ? TRUE : FALSE));
echo form_radio('trailer', '0', set_radio('trailer', '0', $row->videotype === "0" ? TRUE : FALSE));
```

This works for me on Codeigniter 3 on PHP 5.6, should work on other versions too.

Comment: Not working sir. I tried your example but it did not work for me. I get nothing in output and both radio boxes get unchecked after this.

Comment: Have you run validation in the controller? is the variable name same in controller and view?

Comment: yes, sir, both names are same. I have taken the array of all the input field in validation form.